# move_uploaded_file() function doesn't work while referencing to another page

Tags: php

I have problem with move_upload_file() function while referencing it to another page. It works without any mistakes. But the problem is the selected file is not being transferred to the specified directory.

I din't know what's the problem and appreciate any kind of help or suggestions.

Here is the code:

PAGE 1(where input is being done):

```
    <form name='NewsForm' method='post' action='conf_news.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' >

 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value='' >
 <input type='submit' name='AddNews' value='POST' >

 </form>
```

It brings code to another page "conf_news.php" where i reference parts of the stored file:
PAGE 2:

```
     $PicMessage = "";
    $PicName = addslashes( $_FILES["file"]["name"] );
    $PicType = addslashes( $_FILES['file']['type'] );
    $PicSize = addslashes( $_FILES['file']['size'] );
    $PicError = addslashes( $_FILES["file"]["error"] );
    $PicTempName = addslashes( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] );

$allowedExt = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png');
$a = explode(".", $PicName);
$extension = end($a); unset($a);

if((($PicType == "image/gif") 
|| ($PicType == "image/png") 
|| ($PicType == "image/jpeg")
|| ($PicType == "image/jpg") 
&& ($PicSize > 100)
&& in_array($extentions, $allowedExt))){

   if($PicError > 0){
       $PicMessage = "Error Type: ". $PicError. "<br />";
   }

    else{
       echo "Upload: ". $PicName. "<br />";
       echo "Type: ". $PicType. "<br />";
       echo "Size: ". ($PicSize / 1024). " Kb<br />";
       echo "Stored in: ". $PicTempName;


       if(file_exists("../photos/". $PicName)){
          $PicMessage = "File Already Exists";
       }

       else{
           move_uploaded_file($PicTempName, "../photos/". $PicName);
           $PicMessage = "Stored in: ". "../photos/". $PicName;
       }
      }

}

else{
$PicMessage = "Invalid File Type";
}
```

The Picture message displays that the file was transferred but the ptohos folder is empty. I really can't think about what is wrong.

Many thanks in advance to all who will spend their time for helping me.

Comment: check what move_uploaded_file() is returning

Answer (score 2):

Ok.I found out the problem.

in_array(**$extentions**, $allowedExt))){ change that to **$extension**.Its a small mistake but capable enough to delay our work.Also remove add_slashes() and try.

Comment: also remove add_slashes()  and try

Comment: No any changes in my case?

Comment: Be aware that by not escaping your filename, you open up potential security flaws. Find another way to mitigate this, if `add_slashes()` is causing you problems.

Comment: I think mysql_real_escape_string() will do fine.Also you must specify the max upload size limit.Currently you have only minimum size limit ($PicSize > 100).Add maximum size limit like ($PicSize <3000) or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify that the file is actually uploaded with POST request, because as it says in the manual for this function: `move_uploaded_file() ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be moved.` You can verify whether or not the file was uploaded through PHP with the function `is_uploaded_file()`. This will tell you whether or not the file is even capable of being used with `move_uploaded_file()`.

Replace your `else` statement with:

```
else if(is_uploaded_file($PicName)) {
  move_uploaded_file($PicTempName, "../photos/". $PicName);
  $PicMessage = "Stored in: ". "../photos/". $PicName;
}
```

Comment: where should I place is  is_uploaded_file() function?

Comment: Of course, you should add debug statements (such as `echo "is_uploaded_file() returns true here!";` or somesuch) to test what is actually happening in your code.

Comment: "where should I place is is_uploaded_file() function?" Is it a PHP function, just call it

Comment: Yes You are correct the is_uploaded_file(0 shows that there is no file to move. What do you recomment to do in this situation?

Comment: if(is_uploaded_file($PicTempName)){
      move_uploaded_file($PicTempName, "../photos/". $PicName);
   $PicMessage = "YES";
     }
     else{
      $PicMessage = "NO";

Comment: and the message is always NO

Comment: How can i access the file than from another page?

Comment: If you know that your code will be executed only after uploading an image, then you can find another way to move the file. `rename()` is the PHP function that will do this for you.